# What does the symbol '~' mean in MATLAB when I use it before an image?

Tags: matlab

What does `~` mean when I use it before an image?

For example:

```
K = bwmorph(~J,'thin','inf');
```

Where `J` is a binary image.

Comment: adding to fpe's answer, `~J` is a binary matrix where all the non-zero values of J are zeros and all the zero values of J are ones.

Comment: I recommend you try to investigate these things yourself.  In the MatLab environment it's immensely easy to construct a simple binary test image, apply the `~` operator and see the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a logical `not`.

For more detail, please type in

```
doc ~
```

**EDIT**

```
bwmorph(BW,operation)
```

works explicitely on binary images, therefore `~BW` only implies that zeros are position-changed with one, as some of the other members pointed out.

Please check this out:

```
A = eye(5)

~A
```

In your case, black will turn into white and viceversa.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If it's a binary image...sure

Comment: What is the result?  `false`?  An inverted image?

Answer (score 4):

It's the logical not operator in MATLAB.  Read more in the MATLAB help:

> > help not

In your case, it basically inverts the colors of your binary image.  This is because not(1) = 0 and not(0) = 1, with the usual interpretations about 0/1 vs. false/true.

Comment: Ok, this comment may not be constructive, but one must admit that typing "help not" in a CLI is a *very* geeky joke. I'm gonna share this with my colleagues. Thanks for the idea! :-)